# devexpress CheckedComboBoxEdit.DataBindings connect to xpcollection

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, devexpress, xpo

I'm trying to connect xpcollection, below is xpcollection code I'm using:

```
Private Agent As New XPCollection(Of clAgent)(UOW)
```

I would like data from this collection to be visible in CheckedComboBoxEdit, I think it should be DataBindings, however it's not working, or I don't know how to work it out. Any ideas of how to add results from xpcollection to CheckedComboBoxEdit?

Thanks

Patryk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit.DataSource](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit_DataSourcetopic) property to assign a data source to CheckedComboBoxEdit.

```
Private Agent As New XPCollection(Of clAgent)(UOW)
CheckedComboBoxEdit.Properties.DataSource = Agent
```

Comment: so simple ! Thanks a lot!